# numpy newaxis does not always append new axis where I want to

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Why doesn't `np.newaxis` always append the axis where I put it? See example:

```
import numpy as np 
M = np.array([[1,4],[2,5], [3,4]]) 
M[:,np.newaxis].shape
# returns (3, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documents](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) describing `newaxis`:

> The added dimension is the position of the newaxis object in the selection tuple.

In your example, `newaxis` is in the second position of the tuple, hence the new dimension of length 1 is inserted there.

This is analogous to selecting a value at a particular index. For a three-dimensional `A`, you would use `A[:,0]` to retrieve the index `0` value from the second axis, not the third axis.

If you want to add the new axis in the last position of the tuple, you could  write `M[:,:,np.newaxis]` or alternatively use the ellipses notation:

```
>>> M[...,np.newaxis].shape
(3, 2, 1)
```

Comment: Great answer. I was confused because I didn't know the second `,` is optional in numpy, unlike R. So I thought that `np.newaxis` is in the last position instead of second.

Comment: No problem - glad it was useful.